# How can I implement LIKE, NOT IN, IN search functionality with CakePHP and MongoDB?

Tags: php, mongodb, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Currently I am using [ichikaway cake-php](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb) MongoDB plugin to connect my CakePHP with MongoDB, I am facing an issues while executing find method, below is my code.

```
debug($this->Keyword->find("all",array(
    "conditions" => array("Keyword.keyword LIKE"=>"%p%")
)));
```

I get an empty response even though I have data in DB

Is there anything I am missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add your `Keyword` model code to your question.

Comment: @ndm, $p = $this->request->query('q') this is what I get from params

Comment: I'm referring to your `Keyword` model class.

Answer (score 0):

I think should be

```
$this->Keyword->find('all')
     ->where(function($event){return $event->or_([
          'Keyword.keyword LIKE '=>'%'.$this->request->query('search_item').'%',  // if search_item comes through GET method
         ]);
      });
```

Comment: I am using cake 2, I think that code belongs to cake 3